# Find substring that surrounds a pattern using java

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a long string variable `X` and another string(a word or two in length) `Y`. I want to find 50 words before and after `Y` where it appears in `X`. How can I achieve this using reg-ex.

Comment: What is your definition of "word"? Is `hjsdkf` a word? What about `0`? What about `__`? What about `[`?

Comment: In my definition, words are what to get when you split a string by white space. Need not be meaningful.
In the above qstn, Y could be a sequence of words with white spaces. But I am sure it will appear in the same sequence somewhere in X

Comment: What should happen if Y is `hat` and X is `Yeah, whatever!`? (Note that the sequence `hat` is contained in X, but the word `hat` doesn't appear as a word in X). What should happen if Y is `foo` and X is `Foo bar`? (Note the differing capitalization).

Comment: OK. I am sure/can assume that Y will appear in X delimited by a space. 
Both X and Y are in lowercase

Comment: "I am sure/can assume that Y will appear in X delimited by a space" So in other words if Y is `hat` and X is `where's my hat?` then you want it to fail to match because `hat` is followed by punctuation?

Comment: What should happen if Y occurs in X multiple times? `is it my hat or your hat?` (Assuming one word on each side instead of 50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code generates a string of 300 words (Word0 .. Word299), defines the target to search for as `"Word12 Word13"` and then finds up to 50 words before that string and up to 50 words after it.

```
final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
final String matchWords = "Word12 Word13";
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) b.append("Word").append(i).append(" ");
final Matcher m =
  Pattern.compile(
    "((?:\\S+\\s+){0,50})" + Pattern.quote(matchWords) + "((?:\\s+\\S+){0,50})"
  ).matcher(b.toString());
if (m.find()) System.out.println("Words before: " + m.group(1) +
    "\nAfter: " + m.group(2));
```

Comment: @Vijith Updated just now to match **up to** 50 words (if the target occurs within 50 words of front/back of string).

Comment: INFO : It causes error when matchWords contains a "(". So I just replaced any "("s with "\\\(". What to do if similar problem arises.

Comment: This is to be expected, you'll meet new challenges as your requirements grow. Your current problem will be solved in the general by running `matchWords` through `Pattern.quote`. I'll update the code in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why does this have to be an regexp? What if there aren't 50 words surrounding it, because the match is at the beginning of the string?

Consider just locating the match, then separately finding an appropriate "snippet" surrounding it, without trying to cram it all into one magic, unmaintainable regular expression.

There is nothing wrong with doing it explicit: find the match, grow the snippet to the desired size, return the match. Make that a well-documented method "extractSnippet" instead of trying to do it in a single regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Check this PHP regex out, I'm pretty sure it'll work for Java too:

```
php > preg_match_all("/([a-z]+ ){4}donkey( [a-z]+){4}/","summer donna summer donna summer donkey hop hop hop hop bzzp",$matches); print_r($matches);
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => donna summer donna summer donkey hop hop hop hop
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => summer 
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  hop
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Java needs the Java.util.regex.* lib (the last kliny is for the dependancies) to preform that. Import that and invoke an instance such as:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
   sb.append(m.group()); //this appends the context of Pattern p to the appended sb
}
```

In the Pattern, regular regex syntax can be invoked.

I would think you could run into issues where there may not be 50+- words preceding or succeeding the y string.

Roughly, I would say first check for existence with a pattern like *$y* to preform on X.Then go to the expense of counting words with a split operation and a " " space delimiter. From there, its a counting problem.